How to convert multiple columns to rows in shell (unpivoting)
I have a tab separated table with hundreds of columns and rows, like that:
OTUId AC0184 AC0250 AC0257 AC0258 AC0262 AC0263 AC0289 AC0293
OTU549024624 51659 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
OTU565712448 108 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
OTU823308547 11359 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

And I  need to convert it to a 3 column table, like that:
Sample   OTUId         Reads
AC0184   OTU549024624  51659
AC0250   OTU549024624  0
AC0257   OTU549024624  0

I was trying awk, but it not worked as I need. Anyone have a solution?
thanks

please update the question with your awk attempt(s) and the (wrong) output generated by your code

(1) Please try to describe your problem better.   For starters, you say you have “hundreds of columns and rows”, but you show nine columns.   Are there actually more?   Do some rows have different numbers of values? … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) … (2) You can get the output you show with printf '%s\n' 'Sample   OTUId         Reads' 'AC0184   OTU549024624  51659' 'AC0250   OTU549024624  0' 'AC0257   OTU549024624  0'.  Please describe how the output you want relates to the input.  For example, should we assume that you want five more rows with OTU549024624 (for a total of eight), followed by eight rows with OTU565712448 and eight rows with OTU823308547?  … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Make sure the expected output you provide is exactly the output you expect from the input you provide. If you really do only expect 4 rows of 3 column output (12 values) from 4 rows of 9 column input (36 values) then explain the logic that's discarding the rest of the input, otherwise fix your example so we can copy/paste it to test a potential solution with.

Using Miller, given
$ mlr --tsv cat file.tsv
OTUId   AC0184  AC0250  AC0257  AC0258  AC0262  AC0263  AC0289  AC0293
OTU549024624    51659   0       0       0       0       0       0       0
OTU565712448    108     0       0       0       0       0       0       0
OTU823308547    11359   0       0       0       0       0       0       0

then
$ mlr --tsv put -q '
    for (k,v in mapexcept($*,"OTUId")) {emit1 {"Sample": k, "OTUId": $OTUId, "Reads": v}}
  ' file.tsv
Sample  OTUId   Reads
AC0184  OTU549024624    51659
AC0250  OTU549024624    0
AC0257  OTU549024624    0
AC0258  OTU549024624    0
AC0262  OTU549024624    0
AC0263  OTU549024624    0
AC0289  OTU549024624    0
AC0293  OTU549024624    0
AC0184  OTU565712448    108
AC0250  OTU565712448    0
AC0257  OTU565712448    0
AC0258  OTU565712448    0
AC0262  OTU565712448    0
AC0263  OTU565712448    0
AC0289  OTU565712448    0
AC0293  OTU565712448    0
AC0184  OTU823308547    11359
AC0250  OTU823308547    0
AC0257  OTU823308547    0
AC0258  OTU823308547    0
AC0262  OTU823308547    0
AC0263  OTU823308547    0
AC0289  OTU823308547    0
AC0293  OTU823308547    0


Hi! Thanks for the proposal! I tried your suggestion, but returns that: mlr DSL: syntax error at ":"
mlr put: syntax error on DSL parse of 'for (k,v in mapexcept($*,"OTUId")) {emit1 {"Sample": k, "OTUId": $OTUId, "Reads": v}}'

@babinecha what miller version are you using? the syntax is clearly valid in the version I'm using (6.11.0)

you were right! I was using an outdated version. now I update to 6.12.0 and it worked. thank you! also, I tried the script replacing the "emit1" keyword for just "emit" and it worked as well.
